# Select only relevant rows with a specific time difference

Tags: r, datetime

Here is my data:

```
    > str(heard2)
'data.frame':   616 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ DateTime   : POSIXct, format: "2017-07-26 22:28:10" "2017-07-26 22:31:18" "2017-07-26 22:32:18" ...
 $ Transmitter: int  30759 30759 30759 30759 30759 30759 30759 30759 30759 30759 ...
 $ Station    : Factor w/ 35 levels "TRA1-69","TRA2-69",..: 21 21 21 21 21 22 21 22 21 22 ...
```

```
> dput(heard2[c(37:47),])
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1501109904, 1501109950, 
1501109953, 1501110005, 1501110008, 1501110053, 1501110056, 1501110105, 
1501110108, 1501110166, 1501110169), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "GMT"), Transmitter = c(30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 
30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L), Station = structure(c(21L, 
22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 22L, 21L), .Label = c("TRA1-69", 
"TRA2-69", "TRA3-69", "TRA4-69", "TRA5-69", "TRA6-69", "TRA7-69", 
"TRA8-69", "TRB1-69", "TRB2-69", "TRB3-69", "TRB4-69", "TRB5-69", 
"TRB6-69", "TRC1-69", "TRC2-69", "TRC3-69", "TRC4-69", "TRC5-69", 
"TRC6-69", "TRD1-69", "TRD2-69", "TRE1-69", "TRE2-69", "TRE3-69", 
"TRE4-69", "TRE5-69", "TRF1-69", "TRF2-69", "TRF3-69", "TRF4-69", 
"TRG1-69", "TRG2-69", "TRG3-69", "TRG4-69"), class = "factor")), row.names = 45:55, class = "data.frame")
```

The datetime column refers to when a transmitter was detected at a specific station. Most of these detections are 30-60 seconds or more apart. How can I select the rows that correspond with times that are only say 8 seconds (or less) apart?

Comment: are we calculating for each station or each station-transmitter combo?

Comment: @Shree The data I'm currently using is actually only from 1 transmitter. An 8 or less second gap would only be achieved when the tag is heard at 2+ stations almost simultaneously. So I'm really looking for which stations they were and the relevant time gap between those detections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way with `dplyr`. Every row with `timediff <= 8` is a pair with the row above it.

```
heard2 %>% 
  arrange(DateTime) %>% 
  mutate(
    timediff = c(NA_real_, diff(DateTime))
  ) %>% 
  filter(timediff <= 8 | lead(timediff) <= 8)

              DateTime Transmitter Station timediff
1  2017-07-26 22:59:10       30759 TRD2-69       46
2  2017-07-26 22:59:13       30759 TRD1-69        3
3  2017-07-26 23:00:05       30759 TRD2-69       52
4  2017-07-26 23:00:08       30759 TRD1-69        3
5  2017-07-26 23:00:53       30759 TRD2-69       45
6  2017-07-26 23:00:56       30759 TRD1-69        3
7  2017-07-26 23:01:45       30759 TRD2-69       49
8  2017-07-26 23:01:48       30759 TRD1-69        3
9  2017-07-26 23:02:46       30759 TRD2-69       58
10 2017-07-26 23:02:49       30759 TRD1-69        3
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: The original request was not clear if you want the earlier, later or both records. This produces both records.**

Create a variable for checking forward (`lead`) then one for checking backwards (`lag`). Then use `filter` to determine if you want the first (set `dist_lead == 8`), the later (set `dist_lag == 8`), or both (set `filter(dist_lead == 8 | dist_lag == 8)`).

```
k %>% 
mutate(dist_lead = ifelse(lead(Transmitter) == Transmitter,difftime(lead(DateTime), 
                         DateTime, units = "secs"), NA),
dist_lag = ifelse(lag(Transmitter) == Transmitter, difftime(DateTime, lag(DateTime), 
units = "secs"), NA)) %>% 
filter(dist_lead == 8)
```

Comment: I think this is close. I'd like to keep both records somehow so I could have columns: datetime 1, datetime 2, station 1, station 2, time difference. Sometimes there are more than 2 stations at a time though so could need columns for datetime 3/ station 3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be the cross join to the table itself then filter based on time difference. Note that this will return pairs of the same record as well.

```
    library(dplyr)
    heard2$tmp = 1
    dplyr::full_join(heard2, heard2, by = 'tmp') %>% 
      filter(abs(DateTime.x -DateTime.y) <= 8/60) %>% 
      select(-tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, and you need only to label rows which are 8 sec apart, there is a simple solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

mutate(heard2, Grp = cut(DateTime, '9 sec', F, F)) %>%
  semi_join(count(., Grp) %>% filter(n > 1))

#               DateTime Transmitter Station Grp
# 1  2017-07-26 22:59:10       30759 TRD2-69   6
# 2  2017-07-26 22:59:13       30759 TRD1-69   6
# 3  2017-07-26 23:00:05       30759 TRD2-69  12
# 4  2017-07-26 23:00:08       30759 TRD1-69  12
# 5  2017-07-26 23:00:53       30759 TRD2-69  17
# 6  2017-07-26 23:00:56       30759 TRD1-69  17
# 7  2017-07-26 23:01:45       30759 TRD2-69  23
# 8  2017-07-26 23:01:48       30759 TRD1-69  23
# 9  2017-07-26 23:02:46       30759 TRD2-69  30
# 10 2017-07-26 23:02:49       30759 TRD1-69  30
```